# How to restrict an app or monitor other apps activity in android programatically?

Tags: android

I want to create an Android application for conducting Quiz (at University level). While the quiz is progressing, I don't want users to go out of the app and search Internet/use any other app and answer. I dont want the user to exit the app unless they explicity submit/exit the quiz upto what they have done.

I have tried making it as launcher app but I couldn't take control of task switcher button. Also, I was not able to disable notification area.

If I cannot restrict this much, I want to monitor what they are doing while quiz is progressing. I can get any permissions or be device administrator or anything but I cannot restrict internet access as the server of the quiz is in internet. If a call or notification comes, I dont want that to popup while quiz is progressing etc.

Atleast, I want to log everything to server if they have done anything intentional. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered creating a [Kiosk Mode app](http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-1/)?

Comment: Thanks. That article still has recently running apps problem mentioned. I want to avoid that too since the phone is personal and not in our control.

Answer (score 1):

listening for onStop in your Activity might do the trick.

see: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Answer (score 0):

You can finish the activity in onStop() or you can use this on the activity  in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:noHistory="true"
```